# In VS code, I want the down arrow take me to end of line, if I'm in the last line of a cell, but at the end of the last line, go to next cell

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, customization, key-bindings

In jupyter lab in anaconda:

#1) The down arrow generally takes you one line down.

#2) Unless you are at the last line of the cell, in which case it takes you to the end of the line.

#3) Pressing the down arrow while at the end of the last line, will take you to the next cell.

In VS code, by default, #2 doesn't happen. How can I make it happen, while keeping #1 and #3?
I managed to get #2 to happen, using this answer from a similar question:

*For cursor to go from the beginning of the last line to the end of it when pressing arrow down (↓) instead of jumping to the next cell you should open Keyboard Shortcuts (File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts [Ctrl+K Ctrl+S]) and remove or change bindings for "Notebook: Focus Next Cell Editor". Similarly you should change bindings for "Notebook: Focus Previous Cell Editor" if you want the same functionality for the up arrow (↑).*

but it also removed #3. I would also like for it to work when using the up arrow.

Answer (score 0):

The first and third items you proposed are already satisfied in vscode.

For the second item, move to the **beginning/end** of the line. I suggest you use **Home/End** according to the [keyboard reference sheets](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/tips-and-tricks#_keyboard-reference-sheets) to move quickly.

You can modify it in the keyboard shortcuts:

[image]

But please do not use `↓`, because it conflicts with moving line down as you mentioned first item.